# How do I add the <noscript> tag in <head>?

Tags: 7

If I want to add JavaScript in the head tag, I use `drupal_add_js($js, 'inline')`. This will add a `<script type="text/javascript">`.

How do I add the `<noscript>` tag? I want to add the following in `<head>` also.

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=<?php echo $file ?>" />
</noscript>
```

BTW, I'm using a simple module for this.

```
function custom_download_menu() {
    $items['download-code'] = array(
    'title callback' => 'custom_download_page_title',
    'page callback' => 'custom_download_view',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
    return $items;
  }

function custom_download_view() {
    $js = "var time_left = 5;
        var cinterval;

        function time_dec(){
            if(time_left > 0) time_left--;
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Your download will start in ' + time_left + ' seconds...';
            if(time_left < 1){
                clearInterval(cinterval);
                window.location = '<?php echo $file ?>';
            }
        }

        cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);";

    drupal_add_js($js, 'inline');
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add elements to the `<head>` section of a web page using `drupal_add_html_head()`.

```
$target = url('enable-javascript', array('absolute' => TRUE));
$meta = array(
  '#theme' => 'html_tag',
  '#tag' => 'meta',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'http-equiv' => 'refresh',
    'content' => "2; url=$target"
  )
);
$noscript = array(
  '#theme' => 'html_tag',
  '#tag' => 'noscript',
  '#value' => drupal_render($meta)
);
drupal_add_html_head($noscript, 'noscript');
```

[API Documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7)

Comment: If you need to add raw markup you can use the #type => markup and #markup => your_raw_markup. See https://api.drupal.org/comment/11274#comment-11274

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Noscript Tag contributed module.

URL: https://www.drupal.org/project/noscript_tag

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish similar solution in Drupal 9 with this:

```
function my_custom_module_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
$nid=20;
$alias = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'.$nid);
 $noscript = [
  '#noscript' => TRUE,
  '#tag' => 'meta',
  '#attributes' => [
    'http-equiv' => 'refresh',
    'content' => "0; URL=/big_pipe/no-js?destination=$alias",
   ],
];

    $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$noscript, 'noscript'];
    
      return $attachments;
}
```

Hope this help someone in future